# How do I apply claws-mail filters automatically?

Tags: email, email-filter, claws-mail

I've installed claws-mail on arch and created some filters to sort my emails into different folders based on the age of the email. However, I have to manually apply the filters and would like them to apply automatically. I have not been able to find anything in the claws documentation about automatic message filtering, just how to create filters.

I would assume all filters would be applied when I hit the "Get Mail" button, but they are not. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I swear I researched this before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the account preferences and make sure that 'filter messages on receiving' is checked

Comment: It is checked, but it does not filter on receipt. Also I don't think that rule is applicable, because the filter that isn't applying is supposed to move emails I already have once they reach 1 month old. So I have already received them long before a filter is applied.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Claws Mail is not running filtering rules on subfolders.

https://users.claws-mail.narkive.com/rBGGaxJm/firing-filtering-rules-on-imap-subfolders

> No. Automatic filtering on receive works on the INBOX only. You can only trigger filters manually on sub-folders (from the Tools menu).

Answer (score 0):

You should use processing instead of filtering [What is the difference between Filtering, Folder Processing, Pre/Post-processing?](https://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Filtering_and_Processing_of_Messages#What_is_the_difference_between_Filtering.2C_Folder_Processing.2C_Pre.2FPost-processing.3F)

See also [age rule](https://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Filtering_and_Processing_of_Messages#age).